# Parameter Estimation of Dynamical System when Model is known

Tags: optimization, control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

Im working on a nonlinear control based on Lyapunov theory and its working really well. I am able to implement it on a dynamical model of the system in simulink. However I think it has a really big limitation and that is: I cant guarantee that the real system will have the exact parameters that I am modelling. I want to make my lyapunov controller into a more robust controller by adding parameter estimation too it.

I see some texts based around system identification, but I do not need to go that deep, I know what the system looks like. I just need some kind of method to zero in on the drift between my modelled and real components.

Is this possible? I am controlling an DC to AC power converter.

Physical System model:

[image]

Model:

[image]

Controller:

[image]

Comment: It is not really clear what are parameters and what are signals in your system. What exactly do you want to estimate, and with which accuracy? Also, maybe it is a good option to look for a robust controller that can deal with (small) model uncertainties?

Comment: @Arastas I want to estimate the value or R and L. I want the parameter estimation to be independent of the controller.

Comment: Then you should go for online system identification. Maybe Extended Kalman filter will work.
However, your controller is not independent of the estimator: you use your control signal as an input, and you use your estimates to compute the controller. It is a loop.